# Using array.push() inside my own array method gives error (JavaScript)?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code example:

```
function s () {
    this.func = [];
    this.func.addF = function (str) {
        this.func.push(str);
    }
}
```

When I create an Instance of that object:

```
var a = new s ();
a.func.addF ("hello");
```

I get an error saying: **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined**.

I can understand that `this.func` is undefined at that point, but what should I do to make this work. Pls help.

Comment: You're defining `this.func` as an array, but create an object property on top of it.

Comment: Your code is invalid brah. Should be this.addF not this.func.addF

Comment: I know it's invalid. Could you guys pls show me what I should fix.

Comment: Just use `this.push` - within that function, the `this` object is (probably*) going to be the array object itself, not the outer object which contains the array.  (* Depending on how addF is called)

Comment: Please state clearly what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Anyway dont define methods inside your function. Use the prototype instead

Comment: @mike Can you pls show me how to do that?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback

Comment: Do not mutate your questions to something completely different. You can ask a new question.

Comment: @Oriol Oh, I did that, and then people just started marking it as a duplicate for some reason

Comment: I have closed this to the canonical duplicate about `this`, and reopened your other question which is not related to `this`.

Answer (score 4):

There is a problem with `this`. In javascript, `this` point to the binding context or what was used to invoke the function call. The value of this is determined by how a function is called.

```
function s () {
    var self = this;
     self.func = [];
    self.func.addF = function (str) {
        self.func.push(str);
    }
}

var a = new s ();
a.func.addF("hello"); // Display 'hello'
```

Comment: this was helpful. Thanx a lot

Comment: This will absolutely work, however do note it creates a closure that, in this instance, is unnecessary.  This mechanism is needed if addF requires access to any other properties of the containing object, so it's a very useful pattern to know, but in this case there's an alternative that doesn't require creating a closure.

Comment: Actually, when thinking more about it, either method creates a closure, but the use of the `self` free variable guarantees that the outer scope must be captured and cannot be optimized away.

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Could you pls have a look and help me with this similar bug? I just don't get it

Answer (score 4):

Are you trying to add the method to the inner object (the array) or the outer object (the one constructed by s)?

### If the function is intended to be added to the outer object

```
function s () {
    this.func = [];
    this.addF = function (str) {
        this.func.push(str);
    }
}
```

### If the function is intended to be added to the inner (array) object

```
function s () {
    this.func = [];
    this.func.addF = function (str) {
        this.push(str);
    }
}
```

The reason has to do with how `this` is defined.  When you call the method like this:

```
a.func.addF ("hello");
```

the variable `this` does not refer to `a`, it refers to `a.func`.  `a.func` does not have a property `func`, but it does have the method `push`, so if you really intended to add the function to the array object itself, then just use `this.push`.

Comment: I meant the second one. Thanx a lot

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Could you pls have a look and help me with this similar bug? I would really appreciate that