# Function Call Hierarchy in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

My case it this:

```
function s () {
    this.funcs = []; 
    this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
        /* this will push a function to the funcs array, which uses getCoordX() and getPixelY() */
        this.push (Function("pixelX", "var x = getCoordX(pixelX); var f = " + str + "; return getPixelY(f);"));
    }
    function getCoordX(a){
        return 0;
    }
    function getPixelY(a){
        return 0;
    }
}
```

As you can see, in that array I'm adding functions that are created from strings, and those functions need do use getCoordX() and getPixelY(), which are in the s() object. When I try to access them it gives this error: **Uncaught ReferenceError: getCoordX is not defined**.

What should I do to make it work? Please help.

**Edit 2**

How i would use this code:

```
function s () {
    this.funcs = []; 
    this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
        /* this will push a function to the funcs array, which uses getCoordX() and getPixelY() */
        this.push (Function("pixelX", "var x = getCoordX(pixelX); var f = " + str + "; return getPixelY(f);"));
    }

    this.drawCanvas = function() {
        //some code goes here
        this.drawGraph(c);
    }

    this.drawGraph = function (c) {
        c.lineWidth = 2;
        var cnt = 0;    //count how many pixels have been rendered

        for(var i = this.limitLeft; i < this.limitRight; i+= this.pixelwidth) {

            for(var u = 0; u < this.funcs.length; u++) {
                var f = this.funcs[u];
                //some if statements go here
            }
        }
    } 

    function getCoordX(a){
        return 0;
    }
    function getPixelY(a){
        return 0;
    }
}

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.id = "canvas";

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var c = new Canvas("canvas");
c.funcs.addF("2*x");
c.drawCanvas();
```

Comment: how is this question different from that? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304983/using-array-push-inside-my-own-array-method-gives-error-javascript

Comment: Thanks @NinaScholz...

Comment: what do you expect `this` to be if you call `s()` with no context?

Comment: @AndiL.H. This is an English site and comments are public, not just for those who can read German

Comment: @DenysSeguret Sorry for that. Could you please help me understand how to make this work

Comment: @torazaburo I updated my question. I couldn't think of a good title for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do this:

```
function s () {
    this.funcs = []; 
    this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
    /* this will push a function to the funcs array, which uses getCoordX() and getPixelY() */
    this.push (Function("pixelX", "getCoordX", "getPixelY", "var x = getCoordX(pixelX); var f = " + str + "; return getPixelY(f);"));
}

this.drawCanvas = function() {
    //some code goes here
    this.drawGraph(c);
}

this.drawGraph = function (c) {
    c.lineWidth = 2;
    var cnt = 0;    //count how many pixels have been rendered

        for(var i = this.limitLeft; i < this.limitRight; i+= this.pixelwidth)        {

            for(var u = 0; u < this.funcs.length; u++) {
                var f = this.funcs[u];
                var currvalue = f(i, getCoordX, getPixelY);
                var lastvalue = f(i-1, getCoordX, getPixelY);
                //some if statements go here
            }
        }
    } 

    function getCoordX(a){
         return 0;
    }
    function getPixelY(a){
        return 0;
    }
}

var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
canvas.id = "canvas";

document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var c = new Canvas("canvas");
c.funcs.addF("2*x");
c.drawCanvas();
```

This will do it. Hope this helps ;)

Comment: I didn't think about it but it actually did work. `var currvalue = f(i, getCoordX, getPixelY);
                var lastvalue = f(i-1, getCoordX, getPixelY);`

Answer (score 1):

`this` isn't implicit in JavaScript, you must precise it.
Also don't use a string to create a function, just use

```
this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
    var obj = this;
    /* this will push a function to the funcs array, which uses getCoordX() and getPixelY() */
    this.push (function(pixelX){
        var x = obj.getCoordX(pixelX);
        return obj.getPixelY(str);
    });
}
```

Comment: Isn't it like that, that he uses `Function` and not `function`, which would imply that his function would be run in an isolated scope where `getCoordX` or other global references wouldn't be available (except for the fact that the `new` keyword is missing here)?

Comment: I asked about a hour ago here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304983/using-array-push-inside-my-own-array-method-gives-error-javascript, but this is a new case. Those two answers were for part 1

Comment: @Icepickle Could you pls tell me what I should do to make those two functions accessible?

Comment: @AndiL.H. Yeah sure, here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Icepickle/r05m81yh/) that kind of does what you want (though, i'm very unsure what exactly you wish to do with your code :))

Comment: @Icepickle Hi, great example. I didn't write new Function() bc I found some guy who didn't use the `new` keyword and I thought it's not needed. I am trying to make something like Desmos and those two functions help me to get the pixelY for every pixelX on the canvas to make the graph, that's why I had to make a function out of a string. I want to thank you a lot. Is there any other way to make it without having to add the two functions as arguments?

Comment: @Icepickle Thanks a lot. I did something based on your idea and it worked even better than expected

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the Function constructor creates functions which run in the global scope. So your function can't access your `getCoordX` in the closure.

You could make `getCoordX` and `getPixelY` global functions:

```js
function getCoordX(a) {
  return a;
}
function getPixelY(a) {
  return a;
}
function s() {
  this.funcs = []; 
  this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
    this.push(new Function("pixelX",
      "var x = getCoordX(pixelX);" +
      "var f = " + str + ";" +
      "return getPixelY(f);"
    ));
  };
}
var obj = new s();
obj.funcs.addF('x*3 + 5');
console.log(obj.funcs[0](1)); // 8
```

Alternatively, you could use the Function constructor only to evaluate `str`, and move the other code outside.

```js
function s() {
  this.funcs = []; 
  this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
    var f = new Function('x', 'return ' + str);
    this.push(function(pixelX) {
      var x = getCoordX(pixelX);
      return getPixelY(f(x));
    });
  };
  function getCoordX(a) {
    return a;
  }
  function getPixelY(a) {
    return a;
  }
}
var obj = new s();
obj.funcs.addF('x*3 + 5');
console.log(obj.funcs[0](1)); // 8
```

Here you have a full example with canvas:

```js
function s() {
  this.funcs = []; 
  this.funcs.addF = function (str) {
    var f = new Function('x', 'return ' + str);
    this.push(function(pixelX) {
      var x = getCoordX(pixelX);
      return getPixelY(f(x));
    });
  };
  this.drawGraph = function(c) {
    c.lineWidth = 2;
    for(var u = 0; u < this.funcs.length; u++) {
      var f = this.funcs[u];
      c.beginPath();
      c.moveTo(0, 200-f(0));
      for(var x=1; x<400; ++x) c.lineTo(x, 200-f(x));
      c.stroke();
    }
  };
  function getCoordX(a) {
    return a;
  }
  function getPixelY(a) {
    return a;
  }
}
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.width = 400;
canvas.height = 200;
document.body.appendChild(canvas);
var c = new s("canvas");
c.funcs.addF(".5*x");
c.funcs.addF("x + 50");
c.funcs.addF("3*x + 100");
c.drawGraph(canvas.getContext('2d'));
```

Comment: I can't avoid it. I can't use eval in this case because I'm am drawing graphs in a canvas the size of the monitor and there would be a lot of lag. I thought of it before, and I have seen the result

Comment: Maybe you can move the `eval` outside the inner function? Can you include in your question an example of how are you using this?

Comment: I am making a thing like desmos. The user will input something like 2*x+5 and that is the string that is going to come into `str`. I tried to make it with eval() by replacing x with values from the graph but it lags just too much.

Comment: OK, then I think you will need to make the functions global.

Comment: You're assuming that `str` is something that needs to be `eval`'d in one way or another, but I'm suspecting that is not the case, and that he needs to use neither `new Function` nor `eval`.

Comment: @torazaburo See the comment above, the objective is drawing graphs of math expressions. Using `eval` or `new Function` you don't need a math parser.

Comment: I tried your first suggestion before but it didn't work Oriol